# Variance decomposition (svar)

Tags: variance, variance-decomposition

I was reading the [paper by Gromping (2007) about variance decomposition](https://prof.beuth-hochschule.de/fileadmin/user/groemping/downloads/amstat07mayp139.pdf).
I was refering to page 141 (LMG) but I do not know what is meant in statistics by $\operatorname{svar}\left(\{1\}| \emptyset \right)$. Could you clarify this aspect?

In addition do you know any good package for variance decomposition that follows the approach of Lindeman, Merenda and Gold?

Answer (score 3):

1) The definition of $\text{svar}(M|S)$ is given in page 140 of the linked paper: it is the **s**equentially added explained **var**iance when adding regressors with indices in $M$ to a model which has regressors with indices in $S$.

Basically, it is how much more of the variance is explained if you add extra regressors $X_j$, where $j \in M$.

More explicitly, suppose you have the usual linear regression model $$Y = \beta_0 + X_1 \beta_1 + \cdots X_p \beta_p + \epsilon$$ Then $\text{svar}(M|S)$ is defined as

$$ \text{svar}(M|S) = \text{var}(Y|X_j, j \in S) - \text{var}(Y|X_j , j \in M \cup S)$$

So for your example, $\text{svar}(1|\emptyset) = \text{var}(Y) - \text{var}(Y|X_1)$, which is the added explained variance if you add the regressor $X_1$ alone.

2) To decompose the variance following Lindeman, Merenda and Gold, you can use the R package [relaimpo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear. Can the svar be thought also as the remaining variance because from your last example is the variance of $Y$ that you cannot explain with $X_1$

Comment: Not quite, actually $\text{svar}(1|\emptyset)$ is the variance of $Y$ that _can_ be explained by $X_1$. 

To see this, suppose $p = 1$ (for simplicity) and let $\text{var}(X_1) = v_1$ and $\text{var}(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$. Then $\text{var}(Y) = \beta_1^2 v_1 + \sigma^2$, $\text{var}(Y|X_1) = \sigma^2$ and so $\text{svar}(1|\emptyset) = \beta_1^2 v_1$, which is the variance explained by $X_1$.